# How To Run Unsupported .NET 2.0 On Mac M1

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, apple-m1

.net core 2.0 runtime is not supported in visual studio 2022 for mac M1.
Is there any way to run it, i need to run project setup.
Is there any way to run via docker?

To run .net core 2.0 project on mac m1.

Comment: You can't. At least not directly. .NET Core 2 isn't supported anywhere. It was a single-year support version that reached End Of Life 4 years ago in 2018. There was no M1 back then

Comment: Just like other x86 applications you may be able to install the [last .NET 2.0 runtime](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/2.0) and execute the application. For a new application though you should target the LTS version, .NET 6.0, which is supported until 2024

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , any work around to make this work ?

Comment: I already answered that. Just like any other x86 application you need to use x86 emulation. It may or may not work.